# L2 Dirichlet flow of the linear Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, gradient-descent, potential-theory, gradient-flows

I can see how the heat equation (say on $\mathbb{R}^d$) : $\partial_t \rho=\Delta\rho$, can be viewed as a $L_2$ gradient flow of the energy

$$ E(\rho)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla \rho(x)|^2dx.   $$

What is the $L_2$ gradient flow of the Fokker-Planck (in fact Langevin) equation :

$$ \partial_t \rho=\text{div}(\rho\nabla f)+\Delta\rho, $$

for some nice enough function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The Fokker-Planck equation has a nice interpretation as gradient flow in a *weighted* $L^2$-space, if that's of interest to you.

Comment: @MaoWao yeah that would be interesting do you have a link? or could explain further

Comment: More en vogue, would be to consider these equations as Wasserstein gradient flow of the entropy in the case of heat equation and of relative entropy for FPeqn. For the L2 setting, you can just replace Lebsgue measure by $e^{-f}dx$.

Comment: @Tobsn hey thanks for this suggestion, but I am already a bit familiar with Wasserstein gradient flow (WGF). I am trying to understand the benefits of WGF, compared with other viewpoints ( like $L_2$ gradient flow). Do you ever use stack exchange chat room if you have time I would like to ask you a question w.r.t to these things.

Comment: Well, the better your question is, the less likely I'll be able to answer it within a chat :D . Besides my schedule is quite dense.

Comment: @Tobsn so your weighting the $L_2$ norm by the stationary measure? From what I read although I don't think I understand it people weight the $L_2$ measure by the initial distribution say $\rho_0$... See like (8) (9) and (11) here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.03803.pdf

Comment: Yes, for the classical Dirichlet form approach you weight by the invariant measure, say $\mu$, since then $\int |\nabla\phi|^{2}d\mu=-\int\phi L\phi d\mu$ where $L$ is the diffusion generator. It's $L^{2}(dx)$ adjoint $L^{*}$ is then the divergence-form operator appearing in the FPeqn.

Comment: Regarding equation (8) in your reference, that's simply the classical fact that solutions to the continuiuty eqn $\dot{u}=-\nabla\cdot(uF)$ are given by pushing forward the initial distribution with respect to the flow generated by $F$, i.e. $u_{t}={X_{t}}_{\#}u_{0}$ where $\dot{X}_{t}=-F(X_{t})$